# Symfony - Redirect user already logged in

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle

It's possibile with security file config to redirect user already logged in to specific route (e.g homepage) if they try to access on login/register pages? One solution that I already found is to attach a listener to EventRequest, but I prefer to use security config if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

After some googling I noticed that another solution is to override the fosuserbundle controllers. But because I need that this behavior should works also for /register and /resetting pages, instead to override also those controller, I preferred to use EventListener. Maybe this's the best solution in this case. I'm using Symfony 4, so for the other versions could be different.

My code:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class LoggedInUserListener
{

    private $router;
    private $authChecker;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect user to homepage if tryes to access in anonymously path
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $path = $request->getPathInfo();
        if ($this->authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') && $this->isAnonymouslyPath($path)) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if $path is an anonymously path
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isAnonymouslyPath(string $path): bool
    {
        return preg_match('/\/login|\/register|\/resetting/', $path) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

add this to services.yaml:

```
App\EventListener\LoggedInUserListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mintendo, I have errors using your code:

```
request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The token storage contains no authentication token.
php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Exception: The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

Besides that debug bar also showed error and was broken.

But you pushed me in the right direction, so I have modified your code a little.
And it works without errors now:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class LoggedInUserListener
{
private $router;
private $security;

public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, Security $security)
{
    $this->router       = $router;
    $this->security     = $security;
}

/**
 * Redirect user to homepage if tries to access in anonymously path
 * @param GetResponseEvent $event
 */
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request    = $event->getRequest();
    $path       = $request->getPathInfo();

    if ($this->security->getUser() && $this->isAnonymouslyPath($path)) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('dashboard'));
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}

/**
 * Check if $path is an anonymously path
 * @param string $path
 * @return bool
 */
private function isAnonymouslyPath(string $path): bool
{
    return preg_match('/\/login|\/register|\/resetting/', $path) ? true : false;
}
}
```